# What's the recommended way to store current time using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, gmt

My initial approach was:

```
$current = time(); // save this to column CURRENT_TIME with column type VARCHAR

//retrieve it like this
$retrieved = mysql_query(....) //assume query for getting the stored time value
$time = strtotime($retrieved);
```

I have come across the following approaches:

1. use `gmstrftime` to handle gmt
2. use `INT` instead of `VARCHAR` for the column
3. use the mysql function `CURTIME` or `CURDATE`
4. use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` mysql function

none of which were using the `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` mysql var type.

Do you have a better approach for this one?

Comment: Grrr... downvoted without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is recommended to use mysql **timestamp** (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) field type to store time and date variables in **mysql**.

```
$sDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2015-04-07 07:12:51
mysql_query("insert into `table_name` set `created_on` = '$sDate'");
```

It gives you ability to use [mysql functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to compare dates, calculate time differences and so, directly in your mysql query.

Also you can always retrieve the timestamp using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
$result = mysql_query("select `created_on` from `table_name`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$iTimestamp = strtotime($row[0]); // 1428390771
```

Comment: so to store it in the database I need to use date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss) so that it can be compatible with the mysql timestamp? (because I have tried other formats and the column remains 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Comment: i eddited the answer. take a look.
also check manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

I just use the `TIMESTAMP` value type in MySQL, and let MySQL use its own `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can turn a MySQL TIMESTAMP field into a PHP Time() value by using `strtotime()`

Then you just have to make a function that correctly turns a PHP Time() value into a MySQL TIMESTAMP value.

Comment: and the function to turn a PHP time() value into a mysql TIMESTAMP would be?

Comment: @Ygam: you can use MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function to convert for storage into the DB. You can also actually use `UNIXTIMESTAMP()` to convert coming out, as well, if you want to do it DB-side.

Comment: @Ygam You could have Googled this.... :`$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );`

Comment: I have already done that, but the solution I was looking for was to have a timestamp as datatype in mysql and then be able to format it with the date() function:(

Answer (score 0):

Storing it as int is more logical.
You save the row format of date, using which you can later extract other format and more data ..
I also save it as int.

Edit: For(Uni-TimeZone) application int is the fastest way and PHP has great time conversion tools.

Comment: then you never build sites for multiple timezones

Comment: timestamp and date datatypes were invented for several reasons.. plus it give other people an idea of what the data is about.

Answer (score 0):

The format used by MySQL doesn't need to match the format used by PHP. Choose the best on either side. Databases have date data types for a reason; in MySQL you can choose from these:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html

In PHP, you basically have three options:

- Good old timestamps are easy to handle and you can use them in your MySQL queries —see [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)— but they have serious range issues (you can't rely on them for pre-1970 dates, so they are unsuitable for birthdays).
- [DateTime](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects are powerful and builtin, have no range issues and support time zones. However, they are sometimes not very comfortable to use since they seem to lack some important methods.
- You can use a custom date object (third-party or your own DateTime based).