# Saving a datetime string from PHP into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

Alright so I have a datetime string in PHP in the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. For exampe:

```
'2013-07-01 00:04:37'
```

In addition I have a timezone string like:

```
'-05:00'
```

I want to convert these two strings into an integer (unix time) and then store it in a MySQL database. How would you do so?

I know that given a string you can get the unix time as follows in PHP:

```
date_create('2013-07-01 00:04:37')->getTimestamp();
```

However how would you adjust it so that it accounts for the correct timezone? Also how do you store a unix timestamp in MySQL from PHP?

Comment: Have you considered `CONVERT_TZ()` mysql function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysql function `CONVERT_TZ()`

`CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)`

> CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value.

Example:

`SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-07-01 00:04:37','+00:00','-05:00');`

This outputs `2013-06-30 19:04:37` you can use this function in **INSERT** statement.

Comment: Would you give me an example `INSERT` statement? In addition what domain should the column storing the date belong to?

Comment: `INSERT INTO T1(id,date) VALUES (NULL, CONVERT_TZ('2013-07-01 00:04:37','+00:00','-05:00'));` I don't undertsand the other part of your question.

Comment: Thank you. The other part simply meant "should I store the datetime as a DATETIME value or a TIMESTAMP value?" I understand that TIMESTAMP values are converted to UTC from the system timezone before being stored, and vice versa before being retrieved. How would you correctly store the timestamp in such a situation. I was thinking along the lines of `INSERT INTO T1 (id, date) VALUES (NULL, CONVERT_TZ('2013-07-01 00:04:37', '-05:00', (SELECT @@global.time_zone)));`.

Comment: It's up to you how you save it. I prefer datetime but not always(for example when I need collumns to be updated with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). If you want to convert from -5:00 timezone to timezone set in SYSTEM then code that you gave is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the timezone ;)

Something like:

```
date_create('2013-07-01T00:04:37-05:00')->getTimestamp();
```

As you can see in docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Awesome. How would you store this timestamp into a MySQL database?

Comment: `$timestamp = date_create('2013-07-01T00:04:37-05:00')->getTimestamp();`

And...

`INSERT INTO table VALUES time = '$timestamp'` with your PDO / Mysqli extension...

You never do that? :O Check this: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) 

You can set the field as timestamp in mysql ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a time and date to a Unix timestamp, it converts it to an integer that represents the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC. So if you input your timezone into the function to create the timestamp, it will adjust the number of seconds.

You can then save this value in a MySQL `int` column, since the timestamp is a signed integer.  See [How should unix timestamps be stored in int columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289793/how-should-unix-timestamps-be-stored-in-int-columns) for more information on this. You could do something like

`INSERT INTO table (timestamp, content) VALUES ('your timestamp','your content');`

to insert it into your table.