# What size of an INT do I need to store Unix timestamp in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, int

Do I need a MySQL data type `INT` or `BIGINT` to store Unix timestamp that is returned by PHP's [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and used by [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions?

Comment: Why are you not using MySQL built in `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` ?

Comment: Unless there is a very specific reason you need to store 'dates' as integers, I would recommend using MySQL's internal date/timestamp functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should unix timestamps be stored in int columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289793/how-should-unix-timestamps-be-stored-in-int-columns)

Comment: Though you should really be using DATETIME.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Thanks, it seems like `BIGINT` is the way to go to future-proof it. As for `DATETIME`, it was my original design. Unfortunately PHP is so bad at converting dates to and from `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format for MySQL so that I decided to just stick with Unix timestamp for clarity. For instance, I store all my dates in UTC time zone. But when I do those conversions PHP tries to convert it into server's local time that is such a pain!!!

Comment: Use PHP's `DateTime` and then set the timezone to `Europe/London`. http://php.net/DateTime

Comment: Do you really think PHP is better at converting dates to timestamps than to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format? Once you have a timestamp (or a DateTime object), it's an easy step to convert that to the appropriate format.... any problems are parsing human readable dates into a timestamp or a DateTime object; and DateTime objects are timezone aware, so that's even easier

Comment: @MarkBaker: Maybe I'm just used to working with low-level programming languages that just don't do sh*t implicitly (behind my back.) And that's what PHP methods dealing with time seem to be doing IMO. I just prefer working with an `int` knowing that some API won't change time zone on it, etc... may be just me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check PHP's constant `PHP_INT_MAX` to find the maximum integer. This will differ between environments. On my local system:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', PHP_INT_MAX) . '<br />';
// outputs: 292277026596-12-04 09:30:07
```

So the maximum timestamp I can create is:

```
echo mktime(9, 30, 7, 12, 4, 292277026596);
// outputs: 9223372036854775807
```

Anything larger results in something similar to a [2038 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it) (the number turns negative).

So on my particular system, I would need to use mysql's `BIGINT` to store these values, as `INT` only goes up to 2147483647. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it sounds like `BIGINT` is the way to go. And, as someone suggested in comments above, `TIMESTAMP` would not work, as it's implicitly 32-bit. Plus `TIMESTAMP` does those implicit conversions to and from UTC (that drive me crazy!)