# insert time not working mysql

Tags: mysql, time

basically, I have created the following table

```
create table test (t time);
```

after the table is created, I tried to insert values by the following command:

```
insert into test values time(curtime());
```

the last statement generates the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think current function is not working ( i don't know if it there ). You can do one thing- get the current time through PHP or whatever you are using, store in variable and insert into DB. Check this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323945/whats-the-recommended-way-to-store-current-time-using-php-and-mysql) for reference

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the parentheses around `values(...)`

```
insert into test values (time(curtime()));
```

And you should always define the columns you insert into

```
insert into test (t) values (time(curtime()));
```